# Copy exec.Command output to file as the buffer receives data

Tags: go, io, buffer

I have a script that dumps quite a bit of text into STDOUT when run. I'm trying to execute this script and write the output to a file without holding the entire buffer in memory at one time. (We're talking many megabytes of text that this script outputs at one time.)

The following works, but because I'm doing this across several goroutines, my memory consumption shoots up to > 5GB which I would really like to avoid:

```
var out bytes.Buffer
cmd := exec.Command("/path/to/script/binary", "arg1", "arg2")
cmd.Stdout = &out
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
out.WriteTo(io) // io is the writer connected to the new file
```

Ideally as `out` fills up, I want to be emptying it into my target file to keep memory usage low. I've tried changing this to:

```
cmd := exec.Command("/path/to/script/binary", "arg1", "arg2")
cmd.Start()
stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
r := *bufio.NewReader(stdout)
r.WriteTo(io)
cmd.Wait()
```

However when I print out these variables `stdout` is `<nil>`, `r` is `{[0 0 0 0 0...]}`, and  `r.WriteTo` panics: `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`.

Is it possible to write the output of `cmd` as it is generated to keep memory usage down? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just write to a file directly?

```
file, _ := os.Create("/some/file")
cmd.Stdout = file
```

Or use your `io` thing (that's a terrible name for a variable, by the way, since it's a) the name of a standard library package, b) ambiguous--what does it mean?)

```
cmd.Stdout = io
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't realize that was possible (the target file isn't on my machine). Completely agree, just called it `io` to remove irrelevant proprietary stuff from my example but even then probably should have avoided that to remove confusion. Thank you!